# How do I fix a black screen when boot from USB?

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb

I recently destroyed Windows when trying to restore it to default settings. I thought I should give Ubuntu a shot because I'm not going to buy a whole new version of Windows.

I installed Ubuntu 15 on a 8 GB flash drive using Universal USB Installer (UUI). It finished successfully. After that I put the flash drive in my laptop that has no operating system and I opened up the boot options. I made it to boot from the USB.

When I try to boot it says a few words on the top of the top of the screen for a split second. Then it does nothing. No menus, no command line, nothing.

I keep my computer on for a while to see if something will happen, but nothing.

Comment: Did you make sure that the USB drive was formatted in `fat32`?

Comment: In UUI I checked the format box. I'm not sure what file system it formatted the drive to though. I'm assuming it's fat32.

Comment: What is the model of the laptop?

Comment: Its anAcer travelmate 5744

Comment: Go to the Ubuntu website and redownload the 15.10 iso and then use UUI again to burn it to the USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Instead of using Universal USB Installer, I used Rufus. Rufus worked with both Ubuntu MATE and elementary OS. They both successfully booted and installed from USB. I haven't actually tried it with standard Ubuntu but I'm sure it would work.